# Overflow-x not working on mobile device, even with wrapper class

Tags: html, css, animation, overflow

So I have a jQuery animation in a div-element. Clouds are moving from left to right out of the screen and repeat. I append them and then animate it like this:

```
$('#clouds').append("<div id='cloud1' class='cloud'><img src='/images/cloud1.png' ></div>");

function moveCloud1() {
    var cloudwidth = $('#cloud1 img').width();
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    var rand_y = 60 + (Math.random() * 200);
    $('#cloud1').delay(500).css({left: -400, top: rand_y});
    $('#cloud1').animate({
        left: winWidth
    }, (20000+(rand_y*5)), "linear", function() {
        moveCloud1();
    });
}
```

It is all coming together in div's like this:

```
<div class="city_container">
    <div id="clouds"></div>
    <div class='city'></div>
    <div class='sky'></div>
</div>
```

I quickly noticed the ability to scroll horizontally appeared once the clouds were moving outside the viewport on the right, so I added `overflow-x: hidden;` to `body` and even `html`. Finally also to `#clouds` (an element that I added later, hoping to solve this. Before that I just appended the cloud-elements in `city_container`). It works perfectly in regular browsers such as Chrome and Safari, but once I try the website on my iPhone I keep getting the ability to scroll horizonally, this also happens on Android phones. Even when I add `overflow-x: hidden;` to everything that I suspect of allowing this strange phenomenon. (Yes, also to city_container) I really don't know what else to try. I don't want it to allow horizonal scrolling.

For completeness sake, this is included in the head of my html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

I also made sure the width is set to the width of the window. `body` and the wrapper-div both have `width: 100%;`.

Comment: You may need to set an explicit width. Setting overflow doesn't accomplish anything if the browser doesn't know what you wish to hide. Try `body {width: 100%;}`, or maybe `{width: 100vw;}`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I've also tried to keep a close eye on making it have the correct width. I use `width: 100%;` on city_container, body and the div I use to wrap my entire document in.